# Android intent - Display only portion of new activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to display only a portion of `Activity` instead of the whole `Activity`?

What I really want to do is "On clicking a button in  an `Activity`, the page must be redirected to a new `Activity` and only a part or portion of the new `Activity` should be displayed".

Is it possible?

And Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, is not possible to display a portion of activity.

I suggest you to use an activity with multiple [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

In simple cases If you want to show something, then `setVisibility` of that view to `VISIBLE` and other view visibility to `GONE`.

For example, you have two views `view_1` and `view_2`. If you want to show `view_1` alone, then hide `view_2`.